# 複数のチェックボックスで、何がチェックされているか判定を行いたい

Tags: javascript

理想として１がチェックされたら、コンソールログに「１がチェックされました。」
１と３がチェックされたら、コンソールログに「１と３がチェックされました。」
１と２と３がチェックされたら、コンソールログに「１と２と３がチェックされました。」みたいに、チェック判定の処理を行いたいです。

例として１，２，３をあげましたが、これが１～８まであります。
コードを短くしたいのですが、分かる方教えて頂きたいです！

```js
function sample1(checked) {
  if (checked) {} else {}
}

function sample2(checked) {
  if (checked) {} else {}
}

function sample3(checked) {
  if (checked) {} else {}
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" onchange="sample1(this.checked)">1</label>
</div>
<div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" onchange="sample2(this.checked)">2</label>
</div>
<div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" onchange="sample3(this.checked)">3</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

ご質問のサンプルで`onChange`イベントの引数に`checked`プロパティを指定しているので、CheckBox自体を指定するよう書き換えると良いと思います。

`onchange="sample1(this.checked)"` → `onchange="sample(this)"`

それはそれとして、今回の目的はHTMLのすべてのチェックボックスから(※1)選択されているチェックボックスを抜き出し、(※2)親要素の`label`のテキストを「～と～が」のように結合(※3)することです。

コードを短くする用途に限らず、クエリ(※1)やフィルター(※2)、マップ、ジョイン(※3)などの手法はよく使われます。
参考になればどうぞ。

```js
function sample(checkbox){
    // チェックされたコントロールのチェック状況を調べる
    if(!checkbox.checked) return;

    // 複数のチェックボックスで何がチェックされているかを判定する(※1～※3の処理)
    // HTMLのすべてのチェックボックスから
    let checks = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
    // 選択されているチェックボックスを抜き出し、
    let filtered = [].slice.call(checks).filter(c => c.checked);
    // 親要素の`label`のテキストを「～と～が」のように結合
    let s = filtered.map(c => c.parentElement.textContent).join('と');
    console.log(s + 'がチェックされました。');
}
```

```html
<div>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="check1"
onchange="sample(this)">1</label>
</div>
<div>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="check2"
onchange="sample(this)">2</label>
</div>
<div>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="check3"
onchange="sample(this)">3</label>
</div>
```

Comment: 蛇足ですが、選択されているチェックボックスを抜き出す際に [`:checked` 疑似クラス](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)を用いることも出来ます。

Comment: 細かいことですが、ラベルを取るなら「c.parentElement.textContent」より「c.labels[0].textContent」のほうが汎用性が高いかなと思います。